# Accessing Information on other Layers

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have Two layers, the game and the hudlayer. Hud is on top  of HelloWorldLayer.

I've got a button which I press to reload the hudlayer which is just numbers showing up on the screen to capture what's on gameplay.

buttonTapped: is declared on the HudLayer(which goes before HelloWorldLayer) implementation.

HudLayer and HelloWorldLayer are on the same file which is helloworldlayer.m

I press the button and:

```
    - (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
    {
        int number = 6;

    //Heres the problem
       //I dont know how to change this part...

        [[HelloWorldLayer]->changedNumber = Number; ///How do I give changedNumber     Number's value?????


        _label.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number: %d",number];


    }
```

HelloWorldLayer has a property:

```
    @property (assign) int changedNumber;
```

Comment: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Strategies+for+Accessing+Other+Nodes

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your sender is HelloWorldLayer.

You can try:

```
sender.changedNumber = Number;
```

Comment: This can't be, this was one of my first quickfix solutions, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CCArray* layers = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene].children;

for(int i=0; i<[layers count]; i++)
{
    CCNode *node = [layers objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([node isKindOfClass:[HelloWorldLayer class])
    {
        HelloWorldLayer *obj = (HelloWorldLayer*)node;
        obj.changedNumber = Number;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, 'Property _ammoLeft not on object of type HelloWorldLayer'

Comment: _ammoLeft? declare it as property in HelloWorldLayer. Just like you did for changedNumber.

Comment: Im sorry, changedNumber IS _ammoLeft, I just changed it on this example for it to be understandable for everyone.

So basically 'Property _changedNumber not on object of type HelloWorldLayer'